# Non continuous Fuzzy Set

Tags: computational-mathematics, artificial-intelligence, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I stuck in this question for a few hours now. Can anyone help me?

$ A ̃  $ is a non  continuous fuzzy set and is defined by:

$ A ̃ = \{0.6/x_1 +0.5/x_2 +  1/x_3 +  0.75/x_4 +  0.7/x_5 +  0.8/x_6 +  1/x_7 +  0.6/x_8 +  0.8/x_9 +0.2/x_{10}   \} $

For the fuzzy set $ A ̃  $ , find the $FGCount(A ̃ )$, $FECount(A ̃  ) $ and $FLCount(A ̃  ) $ cardinalities.

Note:
$FGCount(A ̃  ) $: The set A has at least i elements

$FECount(A ̃  ) $: The set A has i elements

$FLCount(A ̃  ) $: Set A has at most i elements.

Thank you!

Comment: What are the terms $\mathrm{FGCount}(\tilde A)$,  $\mathrm{FECount}(\tilde A)$ and  $\mathrm{FLCount}(\tilde A)$ defined as?

Comment: I've just put it on the question.